# Not an managed type for Spring Data Mongodb

Tags: spring, exception, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following mongo configuration:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />
<mongo:repositories base-package="com.example.repositories.mongodb" />
```

I have the repository as follows:

```
package com.example.repositories.mongodb;
public interface ReviewRepository extends CrudRepository<Review, String> {...}
```

and the bean:

```
package com.example.domain;
@Document(collection="Review")
public class Review implements Serializable { ... }
```

Unfortunately, when I start the app, I get the following exception:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Could not autowire field: private
>   com.example.repositories.mongodb.ReviewRepository
>   com.example.Controller.reviewRepository; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'reviewRepository': FactoryBean threw
>   exception on object creation; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class
>   com.example.domain.Review

....

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type:
>   class com.example.domain.Review

I think that this might be caused by the repository and the bean it manages not being in the same package. But I get the same issue also when I do place them in the same package. Any ideas?

Comment: it usually means that the persistence layer isn't aware of some class (in this case - Review). do you have both mongo:repositories and context:component-scan set in the same context?

Comment: yes. i have the component scan in the same context. any other ideas? thanks.

Comment: unfortunately, no... aside for not being in the same context, the only other thing that comes to mind (although not likely to happen) is that the @Document annotation isn't the right one. i need to see more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same project we were also using mysql and it was scanning the package: com.example.repositories. This caused the issue and once we changed it to com.example.repositories.mysql it was solved.